# Create row if column does not consist ID from another column

Tags: sql

I have database which contain three tables `product`, `product_size` (variations) and `handbook`. `Product` contains all data about the product, `handbook` knows which size I have and `product_size` contain information about products which have size(s) from handbook and also contain `size_value`.

So I need to insert values in column `product_size` where size_price will contain price of product, handbook_id = 666 and product_id is ID of products which doesn't have product size. Is there any way to do that?

**Product**

```
id
price
name
```

**Product_Size**

```
id
product_id
handbook_id
size_price
```

**Handbook**

```
id
name
```

Answer (score 0):

All products would mean rows from product table. So size may not be in handbook or may not be in product_size table.

```
   Select p.name
   From product p left join
   Product_Size ps
      On p.id= ps.product_id
  Left join Handbook h
      On h.id=ps.handbook_id
  Where handbook_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can phrase the insert like this:

```
insert into product_size (product_id, handbook_id, size_price)
    select p.product_id, 666, p.price
    from product p
    where not exists (select 1
                      from product_size ps
                      where ps.product_id = p.product_id and ps.handbook_id = 666
                     );
```

Note:  This can produce unexpected results if you attempt to run two of these inserts at the same time.  To protect your data from duplicates, you should have a unique constraint/index on `product_size(product_id, handbook_id)`.